# Создать БД для пересечения значений таблицы

Tags: mysql, база-данных, csv

Есть csv таблица в первом столбце даты, в первой строке продукты, нужно получать значения цены из пересечения строки с датой и столбца с номером продукта.
Как реализовать такую БД?
Просмотрел целый курс по базам данных MySql, так и не понял...

Не создавать же для каждого продукта отдельный столбец, а если их тысячи?

Comment: Сюда просится бд (и не надо быть архитектором) с тремя столбцами: дата, продукт, цена. Каждый элемент матрицы будет строчкой. Что тут не так? Что конкретно надо?

Comment: В таком случае у маня получится таблица размером произведение даты на продукты, для БД это нормально?

Comment: Вообще, постановка задачи некорректна, надо как-то так. У вас ограничения по памяти и каждый байт на счету? Вы предусматриваете операции, которые за один раз работают со всеми продуктами? Агрегируете данные за все дни? Продукты добавляются каждый день? А в большом количестве? На скольких серверах будет работать? Будет ли расширение? Какие требования к консистентности и доступности? Что с репликацией? Какое гарантированное время отклика? Как часто будут делаться бэкапы? Будет ли предусматриваться шардирование потом или уже? **А лучше взять схему из ответа ниже и просто попробовать.**

Comment: Если я правильно все понял, то на ваш вопрос нельзя дать однозначного объективного ответа. В предыдущем комментарии я постарался использовать побольше умных слов, которые, тем не менее, встречаются специалистам на практике. Архитекторам больших систем - уж точно! Они должны решать все это разом и сразу оптимально, ведь цена их ошибки может исчисляться большим количеством денег. Главный вопрос: **а какова цена вашей ошибки?**

Comment: Если это и есть разумное и типичное решение для данной ситуации, то у меня нет вопросов, именно так и сделаю.
Я лишь пытаюсь понять существует ли другой способ реализации данной таблицы.
Хотя нет, есть вопрос, какой движок лучше будет использовать в такой ситуации, имеет ли смысл использовать движок CSV?

Comment: CSV - не движок, а просто текстовый формат, в котором можно представить данные... Что значит движок в вашем понимании? Из каких приходится выбирать?

Comment: В моём понимание движок это тип данных выбираемый при создание таблицы в бд...
ПО умолчанию mysql предлагает innodb, потому я и спрашиваю имеет ли смысл выбрать csv, в папке с базой будет лежать файл csv но при редактирование его вручную mysql ругается и говорит что таблица повреждена

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать такую схему:

```
create table products (
    id int primary key auto_increment,
    name varchar(255)
);

create table prices (
    price_date date,
    product_id int,
    price decimal(9,2)
);
```

Нижу прмер содержимого:

```
+============+============+=======+
| price_date | product_id | price |
+============+============+=======+
| 2020-11-13 | 8          | 33.34 |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 2020-11-14 | 6          | 72.47 |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 2020-11-15 | 11         | 76.97 |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 2020-11-16 | 10         | 10.19 |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 2020-11-17 | 10         | 0.95  |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 2020-11-18 | 6          | 26.36 |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 2020-11-19 | 10         | 92.26 |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 2020-11-20 | 9          | 15.65 |
+------------+------------+-------+
```

Запрос для выбоки цены:

```
select price where price_date = '2020-11-17' and product_id = 10;
```

Протестировать схему на [SQLize.online](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=1d9abeb92a7d4a4831479fc95304a6bf&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql80)

Comment: Да, только такой вариант мне и виделся, но на данный момент мой csv файл выглядит правильней и компактней.
Для баз данных норма дублирование данных? я к тому что, в такой таблице у меня для каждого продукта будет целая строка сочетающая в себе дату и продукт... Тогда как в csv файле я вычисляю результат по "координатам" подобно игре  морской бой...

Comment: Приведенный метод являутся стандартным для реляционных баз данных. Он оптимален для хранения больших данных и быстрой выборки, без загрузки всех данных в память